# docker volume doesn't get mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

next to the `compose.yaml` I have a folder called `webroot`,

in`compose.yaml` I have:

```
    build:
      context: .
      target: final
   volumes:
      - webroot:/app/.well-known:rw
```

I build and run my docker image like this:

```
docker build -t cont1 . 

docker run -d -p 81:8080 -p 443:443 --name my-cont1 cont1
```

after I use

```
docker exec my-cont1 ls /app
```

to check for the presence of `.well-known` and it's not there,
also If I do `docker inspect cont1`, there's no "Mounts" present in the result.

Comment: `docker run` doesn't use any of the settings from your `docker-compose.yml` file.  You need to use the Compose tool for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @david-maze answer.

Docker Compose (`docker compose`) is a tool that takes an input a `compose.yaml` file and can build, run and network (usually multiple) containers. See [`docker compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/compose/up/)

Assuming you have a valid and complete `compose.yaml` file, you could:

```bash
docker compose up \
--file=compose.yaml
```

Alternatively (!), you can use `docker run` to run individual containers. When you use `docker run`, you must provide the configuration (that Docker Compose obtains from e.g. `compose.yaml` files) directly. See [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/).

The equivalent commands (!) would be:

```bash
# Build it
docker build \
--tag=cont1 \
${PWD}

# Run it
docker run \
--detach \
--name=my-conti \
--publish=81:8080 \
--publish=443:443 \
--volume=webroot:/app/.well-known:rw \
cont1
```